# i want to add/pass the value to my radio button to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form id = "login" action="#" method="POST" >
            <input type = "text" name = "Name" required placeholder="Name" class="input"><br />
                <div>
                    <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cand ";
                            $result  = $con->query($sql);
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            echo "<table border='2'". 'class="container2"'.">
                            <tr>
                            <th>Number</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Photo</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Voters</th>
                            <th>Vote</th>
                            </tr>";
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                                    echo "<tr>
                                    <td>" . $row["ID"]."</td>
                                    <td>" . $row["cName"]. "</td>
                                    <td>" ."<img src='img/" . $row["cPic"]. "'>"."</td>
                                    <td>" . $row["Position"]."</td>
                                    <td>" . $row["Vcount"   ]."</td>
                                    <td>".'
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="vote" name="vote" value="vote">'."</td>
                                    </tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</table>";  
                        }
                    ?>
    </div>
            <button name = "login" type="submit">Vote</button> 
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<?php 
 
  if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $vote = $_POST['vote'];
    $sql = "INSERT into cand (Vcount) VALUES ('$vote')";
    $con->query($sql);
    }

?>
```

Everytime i submit it doesn't add the value of radio button to database table called `cand`, column `Vcount`. It still displays `0` but it keeps adding a new blank row every time I submit the form.

[image: See this one]

Comment: i forgot to change from checkbox to radio type

Comment: `id` and `name` should be unique. The `radio` type change resolved issue? You are open to SQL injections. Also if you want to `update` you should not have `insert` query, not clear though if that is incorrect.

Comment: yes the ID is AI and the name is unique

Answer (score -1):

You have not properly joined strings, you should do:

```
$sql = "INSERT into cand (Vcount) VALUES ('" . $vote . "')";
```

Comment: What they have is as valid as this... Neither should be used.